# How to build a simple CRUD LDAP on JAVA SPRING?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

i need a simple crud for LDAP in java im follows the next tutorial :

`https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-ldap`

but i cant do it work....
i only need get work this class in a new code for a SIMPLE LDAP CRUD....

`https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-ldap/src/main/java/com/baeldung/ldap/client/LdapClient.java`

```
public class LdapClient {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ContextSource contextSource;

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public void authenticate(final String username, final String password) {
        contextSource.getContext("cn=" + username + ",ou=users," + env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.partitionSuffix"), password);
    }

    public List<String> search(final String username) {
        return ldapTemplate.search(
          "ou=users",
          "cn=" + username,
          (AttributesMapper<String>) attrs -> (String) attrs
          .get("cn")
          .get());
    }

    public void create(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("ou", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextAdapter context = new DirContextAdapter(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.bind(context);
    }

    public void modify(final String username, final String password) {
        Name dn = LdapNameBuilder
          .newInstance()
          .add("ou", "users")
          .add("cn", username)
          .build();
        DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);

        context.setAttributeValues("objectclass", new String[] { "top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "inetOrgPerson" });
        context.setAttributeValue("cn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("sn", username);
        context.setAttributeValue("userPassword", digestSHA(password));

        ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
    }

    private String digestSHA(final String password) {
        String base64;
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            digest.update(password.getBytes());
            base64 = Base64
              .getEncoder()
              .encodeToString(digest.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "{SHA}" + base64;
    }
}
```

How i can get a simple LDAP CRUD with above functionalities?

i need create and edit params user LDAP is for study...

if you know other way to get the CRUD on LDAP please let me know...

Thanks..

EDIT1: Adding errors..

When run app get the follows errors...

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-12 09:58:45.701 ERROR 37524 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/directory/shared/ldap/exception/LdapNameNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at com.santander.ConexionLdapApplication.main(ConexionLdapApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/directory/shared/ldap/exception/LdapNameNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/directory/shared/ldap/exception/LdapNameNotFoundException
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer$ContextSourceBuilder.startEmbeddedLdapServer(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:566) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer$ContextSourceBuilder.build(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:550) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer$ContextSourceBuilder.access$100(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:445) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.getContextSource(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:380) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.build(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:95) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:374) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.configure(LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.java:61) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:349) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:303) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.authenticationManager(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:273) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:208) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:319) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:96) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at com.santander.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$709f159d.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:126) ~[spring-security-config-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.exception.LdapNameNotFoundException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What is it you cannot get to work? You get an error? Your question doesn't provide much information except it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for you reply, added some errors.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.directory.shared.ldap.exception.LdapNameNotFoundException` is pretty clear. YOu are missing a dependency.